# How to get the name of last installed application

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've write a broadcast receiver to detect apps installation event like this

```
  <receiver android:name="ApplicationBroadcastService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Now, i want to catch the name of this last installed application, How could i do it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `Uri` in the `Intent` (obtained via `getData()`) will contain the package name of the app that was installed. You can then use `PackageManager` to get more details about the app given the package name.